# Only trigger selector from applicationSignifigantTimeChangeNotification at midnight

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I added an observer in my main view controller to get called when applicationsignifiganttimechange gets triggered, but I only want that to happen at midnight. By nature, applicationsignifiganttimechange happens when time format changes, and time zones changes, Etc. I need to know how I can focus it down to only at midnight.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your app will even be running at midnight?

Comment: Needs to happen all in background. To my knowledge applicationsignifiganttimechange should que up all notification even if app isn't in foreground